# jqueryUI datepicker in fancybox does not work

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, fancybox

I have this strange problem. When I put an input with datepicker class into a fyncybox wrap, datepicker does not show up when I click on that input.

```
<a href="#test" class="fancybox">Open</a>
<div id="test" style="display:none;width:300px;">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque blandit, mi sed
</p>
<input type="text" class="datepicker"/>
</div>

$(".datepicker").datepicker();

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    afterLoad   : function() {
        this.inner.prepend( '<h1>1. My custom title</h1>' );
        this.content = '<h1>2. My custom title</h1>' + this.content.html();
    }
});
```

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/svsdx/3883/) on fiddle.

Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I have eventually found these two solutions:

FIRST:
[fiddle of first solution here](http://jsfiddle.net/svsdx/3883/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.datepicker', function(){ 
    if (!$(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker')) { 
        $(this).datepicker(); $(this).datepicker('show'); 
    }
}); 

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    afterLoad   : function() {
       this.inner.prepend( '<h1>1. My custom title</h1>' );
       this.content = '<h1>2. My custom title</h1>'+ this.content.html();
    }
});
```

SECOND:
[fiddle of second solution here](http://jsfiddle.net/svsdx/3885/)

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
   openEffect  : 'none',
   closeEffect : 'none'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is confusing jquery ui, because your are copying the html.

```
 this.content = '<h1>2. My custom title</h1>' + this.content.html();
```

You can see this happening when removing the `display: none`. Try add html to the original div, this will work fine:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    afterLoad   : function() {
        $("#test").prepend( '<h1>1. My custom title</h1>' );
        $("#test").prepend('<h1>2. My custom title</h1>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. Your solution worked, byt I eventually found another two solutions to my problem. I have posted them here as well.